# Why does Logan remember Yashida?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

[*The Wolverine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/) starts with the eponymous protagonist's encounter with *Yashida* during World War II. This does clearly happen before the events of [*X-Men Origins: Wolverine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/), during which he completely loses his memory, which is also a major plot element of the X-Men trilogy. Yet, in the most recent events in *The Wolverine* he can clearly remember *Yashida* and their experiences back then.

Now I know that there are other significant and yet to be resolved (or not) [continuity problems](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8839/49) between the different X-Men franchises, so maybe this is just one of them. But it may very well be that I just missed something in the story of the movies or this is explained elsewhere (maybe he suddenly got all his memories back when he remembered *Striker*'s experiment in [*X2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290334/)?). So **is there any information why *Logan* is able to remember *Yashida* from before his amnesia?**

Comment: +1 for noticing this! He did seem to start regaining his memory in X2, so maybe this can be explained by the passage of time.

Answer (score 3):

Why not?

As you mentioned he got remembered Striker's experiment in X2. The same time he may also have remembered all part of his lost memory or triggered some regeneration of lost brain cells process (IMAHO he is a mutant with re-generating capability).

Fox was already starting fixing their continuity problems before The Wolverine, so it's not a stand-alone or continuity problem. Fox is planing big in upcoming years and now wasting time in showing one more telepath helping Wolverine to get his memory back will surely take some screen time which might look unnecessary to them.

For comic fans Wolverine is very tricky in loosing and gaining memory, [I mean it has happened so many times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/how-many-times-has-wolverine-lost-his-memories). So nobody (at least not me) will like to see it again and again. So it's a good step not to mention memory loss again.

One other explanation can be the passage of time as mentioned by @Vedran Šego, anyways [who says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amnesia#Treatment), lost memories can't come back?

Comment: Good points. So I guess the answer is *no* to both possibilites of either being an inconsistency or having been explained anywhere.

Comment: Found similar question over [scifi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40104/why-does-logan-remember-wwii-in-the-wolverine)

Comment: Any points from there you want to integrate into your answer?